# best way to check if a list does or does not contain a series of values in the same order? (python)

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I need a function that takes a list and checks if `['x','y','z']` is `in`/`not in` that list in the exact same order.

For example:

```
list = ['_','x','y','z','_']
if ['x','y','z'] """not""" in list: # `not in` is the actual format of function but commented out to make example easier to explain
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I want:

- If the list is `[,'_','x','y','z','_']`, then return True
- If the list is `[,'_','x','y','a','_']`, then return False
- If the list is `[,'_','x','z','y','_']` then return False

etc.

(Note: the `not` is commented out because the actual function should return True `if ['x','y','z'] not in list:` but it is easier to explain without the `not` condition.)

Comment: Can you change your lists into strings? The `in` operator would work like you want with strings.

Comment: Do not use `list` as a variable name as you are overwriting the built-in `list` function.

Comment: @it_is_Chris I'm not using `list` as a variable name, I'm just using it here to clarify the type.

Comment: @MuteKn0wM0RE you are using it as a variable that is literally what `list = ['_','x','y','z','_']` is doing

Comment: @ it_is_Chris I mean I'm not using the name `list` in the actual code. If you want I can change it to `not_built_in_list_func`. I'm just trying to make the question more readable.

Comment: @MuteKn0wM0RE: We only know what we see in your posting. We have to assume that this is your real code. You should post your real code because you may have missed a vital detail which materially changes what the question is all about.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for the pointer. Next time I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def your_function(list_of_chars):
    return "xyz" in "".join(list_of_chars)
your_list = ['_','x','y','z','_']
your_function(your_list)  # == True
```

Answer (score 2):

if you merge your list into a string using the .join() function you could then simply write:

```
if 'xyz' not in string:
 return true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ['_','x','y','z','_']
order = ['x','y','z']
def f(l,o):
    i=0
    j=0
    while i<len(l) and j<len(o) :
        if(l[i]==o[j]):
            i+=1
            j+=1
        else:
            i+=1
    else:
        if j==len(o):
            return True
        else:
            return False
            
            
print(f(list,order))
```

You can use this algo for your task.It loop thtough both order and list and check whether order in there.